# Hausdorff measure independent of metric

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

I have seen in several papers the claim that for a compact Riemannian manifold the Hausdorff measure will be independent of the Riemannian metric chosen.

Could someone explain what this means exactly and why it is true? I would be inclined to believe that this is the case for the Hausdorff dimension but I don't understand why it would be true for the measure?

Maybe I am missing something obvious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is obviously false as it stands.  If you multiply distances by a constant factor $c$, you multiply $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure by a constant factor $c^d$.

Comment: Ah OK, I thought so. I think maybe they are just referring to finiteness of the measure, if this still makes sense? I guess this would also mean the Hausdorff dimension is invariant?